# How does the RNG work in Salmon Run?

Tags: splatoon-2

I have noticed some strange quirks with seemingly random aspects of Salmon Run, and am wondering if there are known explanations. I'm usually ranked Profreshional in the 0 - 100 range, if that matters.

1. I have noticed that "Known Occurrences" (the special waves) tend to repeat within a short period. For example, a [Rush](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Rush) occurs in the first wave, and the team wipes. The next game or two I join are highly likely to also start with a Rush on the first wave. **Is the Known Occurrence RNG seeded based on time intervals?** This might mean, for example, that every Salmon Run match that starts between 4:00 and 4:10pm will have the same set of Known Occurrences occur on the same waves.
2. **How does the game determine which player gets which special weapon?** This initially appears to be completely random, but I have noticed that if I play for several hours, the game often eventually starts giving me the Bomb Launcher every single time. One time I played back to back games for over 3 hours and got the Bomb Launcher in every game except one. There's no way this is just a coincidence.
3. I have noticed that during the [Goldie Seeking](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Goldie_Seeking) Known Occurrence, occasionally there will be a player who always knows exactly where the Goldie will spawn. They get it right on the first gusher every single time, without even waiting for someone else to guess. **Is there a 100% predictable pattern to the seemingly random spawns, or are these players cheating?**

Comment: Technically there is a possibility that the game randomly selected you back to back for three hours worth of games, if there wasn't a possibility it wouldn't be random.  =-)

Comment: Stupid question: those 3 hours were played with random people online or with your friends?

Comment: @Millard If we assume an average of 10 games an hour (which would be usually finishing all 3 waves), 3 hours is 30 games. Your odds of rolling the same 1/4 chance 29 times are worse than your odds of winning the lottery jackpot... twice in a row.

Comment: @pinckerman One friend and two randoms

Comment: Out of curiousity I tried calculating the odds using the basic calculator and the answer was 3.469447e-18.  Wish I could see that in fraction form.  So fair enough, lol

Comment: Also that result is too small because I accidentally calculated for it happening 29 times instead of 30.

Comment: It's possible that you (or your friend) were considered as host for all those Salmon runs, resulting in the matchmaking never re-rolling special weapons.

Comment: @pinckerman Interesting. Is that known to be how it works, or are you speculating? It seems strange that every time it happens, I'm stuck with grenades

Comment: Just speculation, sorry, I'd have posted it as an answer if I had proof of that.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer for #3, at least.

There seems to be a random chance for Goldie Seeking to have a special condition, where if you don't kill the Goldie and it escapes into a pipe, it will always come back out of the same pipe that it escaped into. This does not happen during every round of Goldie Seeking, but it seems like if it happens more than once, it will happen every single time for that round. When I noticed this happening during one round, I was able to immediately bring the Goldie back out each time he escaped into a pipe.